# Short programming: need help with pointers

Tags: c++

```
#include<stdio.h>    
int main()
{
    int i=10,a;
    while(i>0)
    {
        scanf("%d",&a);
        printf("%d\n",(a+a*a)/2);
        i--;
    }
}
```

Now what i want to ask is how to make it shorter? Maybe some way using pointers instead of variables? Maybe this: `(a+a*a)/2` can be done better?

Comment: I don't quite understand what you mean by "shorter". What's your goal here?

Comment: Hum, why do you want to do this? Making it shorter will make it harder to read...

Comment: You can make it shorter by eliminating all the whitespace in your `main()` function! Seriously speaking, why are you worried about making it shorter? There's no maximum character count limit in programming. Program for readability/clarity/conciseness; not for meeting some arbitrary character count.

Comment: Actually, you should be looking for ways to make this longer, not shorter. Specifically, you should be checking the return code from `scanf`.

Answer (score 6):

Beware what you ask for...

```
#include <iostream>

int main() 
{
    int a; 
    for (int i = 10;
         i-- && (std::cin >> a) && (std::cout << (a + a * a) / 2); )
        ;
}
```

(this also includes error checking, which you didn't bother with)

EDIT: Chris's comments below reveal this to be a terse-programming challenge (and not about legibility, robustness etc.).  His teacher claims a 54 character implementation.
Have to wonder whether that include spaces and newlines?

The tightest implementation I've got so far is:

```
#include<iostream.h>
int main(){for(int i=10,a;i--;)cin>>a,cout<<(a+a*a)/2;}
```

This uses the deprecated header `iostream.h` to remove the need to explicitly find `cin` and `cout` in `std::`.  It's still 74 characters (LF newlines on both lines).

As a thought experiment, let's assume we had a header "x" that declared functions `int g()` (get an int from stdin) and `void p(int)` (write an int to stdin).  The implementation would then be...

```
#include<x>
int main(){for(int i=10,a;i--;)a=g(),p((a+a*a)/2);}
```

...which is still 64 characters.

Another technique commonly used to shorten code is preprocessor tricks, but the obvious one here - loop unrolling - doesn't look promising.  It could look like...

```
#define X ...
int main(){X X X X X X X X X X}
```

...but if you compare `for` loop code to the `#define`-necessitated code...

```
for(int i=10,a;i--;)
#define X X X X X X X X X X X
```

...we're clearly going backwards.

Summarily, I simply can not imagine any approach shaving 10 characters off the `<iostream.h>` version above.  If he has a 54-character implementation, I think the requirements must have been miscommunicated in the question.  If not, I do hope Chris will post it later :-).

Comment: While ironic, this is still pretty neat (even if nobody should use this anywhere near production code).

Comment: @Etienne: I just can't bring myself to do it! :-)

Comment: That would be the truly hideous: `int main(){int a;for(int i=10;i--&&(std::cin>>a)&&(std::cout<<(a+a*a)/2););} ` which would be fine for code golf but if I ever catch anyone in the real world doing that, I'll flay them alive :-)

Comment: @paxdiablo: That is scary. Probably scary enough so that the OP does not want it that short anymore.

Comment: @paxdiablo, I think it can be shortened even more ;), you can save yourself one declaration.. `int main(){for(int i=10,a;i--&&(std::cin>>a)&&(std::cout<<(a+a*a)/2););}`

Comment: int main(){for(int i=10,a;i--&&(std::cin>>a)&&(std::cout<<(a+a*a)/2););}
This one gives wrong answers. The limit is 53 digits: this is the record of my teacher, now this code has around 100 digits....so its still a lot. With std:: a need to include iostream.

Comment: The new code is like this:
#include<stdio.h>
int main(){for(int i=10,a;i--&& scanf("%d",&a)&&printf("%d\n",(a+a*a)/2););}

94 characters :)

Comment: @Chris: How about telling us what your original task was? There is probably a much easier if your teacher requires it to be less than 54 letters (for breaking the record)....

Comment: @Chris: Nim's code doesn't give wrong answers, although not outputting newlines can make it confusing on screen.  Some more comments in the edit to my response.  Please do check the exact requirements, as we've inferred them from your posted solution.

Comment: 63 chars in C89: `main(i,a){for(i=10;i--;printf("%d\n",a+a*a>>1))scanf("%d",&a);}` Reducing this more would probably require abusing the stack.

Answer (score 2):

One way you can shorten this is to use a `for` loop instead of a `while` loop. Try using

```
for (i = 10; i > 0; --i) {
```

Rather than your current `while` statement. This eliminates the need for the `i--;` line.

I'm not sure what you mean by making this code shorter "using pointers" though. Adding pointers won't help here.

Using this `for` loop, your code would look like:

```
#include<stdio.h>    
int main()
{
    int i, a;
    for (i = 10; i > 0; --i)
    {
        scanf("%d",&a);
        printf("%d\n",(a+a*a)/2);
    }
}
```

This removes one line. The only way of removing more lines would be to make this code less readable, or by changing your code style (which is completely unnecessary).

Comment: Need to write the for loop starting at 10 and counting down, to match the original code.

Comment: @David: Since `i` isn't used in the loop, and `main()` ends right after the loop, it doesn't really matter.

Comment: true, and I agree that counting up is more idiomatic